# MYSQL - update text values in table without select, with case (updates in one query)

Tags: mysql

I have got an issue with problem named in topic. 
I am trying to update multiple rows in table in one query depending on specific id of row. Unfortunatelly rows I want to update are text type of data (with numeric data it's easy). This is my query:

```
UPDATE table SET column = CASE
WHEN id = 2 THEN column = column + ', 100'
WHEN id = 3 THEN column = column + ', 10'
[...]
ELSE column
END;
```

Data in column is imploded from php so it looks like:

```
id | column
------------
 2 | 5, 6, 20
 3 | 7, 12, 200
```

After executing a query i would like to have:

```
id | column
------------
 2 | 5, 6, 20, 100
 3 | 7, 12, 200, 10
```

How to add those values to specified rows? For now it changes 'column' row with id 2 and 3 to 0 (like it was an integer type of value).

I also would like to ask you how to erase specific value from column isntead of adding it:

```
id | column
------------
 2 | 5, 7, 20
 3 | 7, 12, 200
```

and i want to remove '7, ' from both rows - with id 2 and 3 so after query it looks like this:

```
id | column
------------
 2 | 5, 20
 3 | 12, 200
```

Any help would be appreciated - i got stuck with it :/

Comment: No, you should accept the answer by clicking the big empty tick to make it a green tick: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask You should read the normalization thing (especially this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_within_columns ) if you are responsible of designing the schema of the database above.

Comment: i havent noticed that 'tick' earlier :)  my bad :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Insertion:

```
UPDATE table 
   SET column = CASE
      WHEN id = 2 
      column =  CONCAT(column, ', 100') 
      WHEN id = 3 
      column =  CONCAT(column, ', 10') 
      ELSE 0
      END
```

For Removing you can do like dis. Sorry ,I can't executes the query right now.Not Tested!

```
UPDATE table 
   SET column = CASE
      WHEN id = 2 
      column = replace(column,', 7','')
      WHEN id = 3 
      column = replace(column,', 7','')
      ELSE 0
      END
```

For Updating: If you want to change the value of 7 to 14

```
    UPDATE table 
   SET column = CASE
      WHEN id = 2 
      column = replace(column,'7','14')
      WHEN id = 3 
      column = replace(column,'7','14')
      ELSE 0
      END
```

Comment: hank you a lot. I found this answer for myself too :)
First example is not working but you can do it using CONCAT function:

    UPDATE table SET column = CASE
    WHEN id = 2 THEN CONCAT(`column`, ', 99')
    WHEN id = 3 THEN CONCAT(`column`, ', 101')
    ELSE column
    END;

Problem solved. Once again with buddies from Stack overflow - i canb always count on you, thx.